# Chisel function for mux with more than two inputs

Tags: chisel, multiplexing

What single function can I use in chisel to represent a multiplexer with more than two inputs (choices)?

MuxLookup()?

Answer (score 3):

You can cascade 2-input `Mux`es, describe the behavior through a hierarchy of `when`/`elsewhen`/`otherwise` statements, or use `MuxCase` to describe an n-way Mux

```scala
result := MuxCase(defaultValue, Array(sel0 -> value0, sel1 -> value1, ...))
```

`MuxLookup` implies comparators (in addition to the multiplexers) to match the value of a signal to a number of values.

A good description of different chisel Mux constructs is available here:
https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/muxes-and-input-selection.html